# Hierarchical List to Return Root and Highest Level Parent

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to build a basic dependency injection container to give myself a better understand of how they work. One of the parts of my container is mapping an alias to a class name. This class can then be mapped recursively to produce a hierarchical list. It must also handle cases where it is mapped to itself.

For example say I have the following mapping:

```
var map = new List<Map>() {
    { new Map("Foo", "Foo") },
    { new Map("foo", "Foo") }
};
```

Where Map is:

```
public class Map {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public Map(string name, string @class) {
        Name = name;
        Class = @class;
    }
}
```

I'd like to write a method (GetMap) which will return the root (name) and the highest level parent (class) for a given name. For example say I said:

```
var map = GetMap(map, "Foo");
var map2 = GetMap(map, "foo");
```

Both variables would return a new Map with the name "foo" and class "Foo". Here's another example to further explain. Given the following map:

```
var map = new List<Map>() {
    { new Map("Foo", "FooExtended") },
    { new Map("foo", "Foo") }
};
```

It would produce a new Map with the Name "foo" and class "FooExtended".

Here is my first attempt:

```
private Map GetMap(List<Map> map, string @class, string name = null) {
    var item = map.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == @class);

    if (item != null && @class != item.Class) {
        return GetMap(map, item.Class, @class);
    } else {
        return new Map(name ?? @class, @class);
    }
}
```

This correctly returns a Map with the correct class for both examples. However the name returned is "Foo" for both examples. This should be "foo" since that is the root of the hierarchy.

I hope I've explained that well enough. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public Map GetMap(List<Map> map, string name, string finalName = null) {
    var item = map.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == name);

    if (item != null && name != item.Class) {
        return GetMap(map, item.Class, finalName ?? name); // <- for you, name ?? @class
    } else {
        return new Map(finalName ?? name, name);
    }
}
```

You need to pass the `name` (or in my case `finalName`) along the entire execution path

**EDIT - This isn't a full solution but I am leaving it**

I renamed the parameters in my test so it was easier for me to read, sorry about that.

My entire LinqPad code

```
void Main()
{
    var map = new List<Map>() {
        { new Map("FooExtended", "FooExtended2") },
        { new Map("Foo", "FooExtended") },
        { new Map("foo", "Foo") }
    };

    var newMap = GetMap(map, "foo");
    newMap.Dump(); // Gives Map("foo", "FooExtended2")
}

public class Map {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public Map(string name, string @class) {
        Name = name;
        Class = @class;
    }
}

private static Map GetMap(List<Map> map, string name, string finalName = null) {
    var item = map.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == name);

    if (item != null && name != item.Class) {
        return GetMap(map, item.Class, finalName ?? name);
    } else {
        return new Map(finalName ?? name, name);
    }
}
```

**EDIT AGAIN - Actual answer based on comments**

Final answer, `GetMap` will return the name of the highest type (EG, `foo`) and the class of the lowest (EG `Foo`)

```
private static Map GetMap(List<Map> map, string name) {
    return new Map(GetMapName(map, name), GetMapClass(map, name));
}

private static string GetMapName(List<Map> map, string name) {
    var item = map.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name != name && m.Class == name);

    return item != null ? GetMapName(map, item.Name) : name;
}

private static string GetMapClass(List<Map> map, string name) {
    var item = map.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == name && m.Class != name);

    return item != null ? GetMapClass(map, item.Class) : name;
}
```

I used the code I posted above and I get "foo", "FooExtended2" no matter what name or class I use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer your naming anyway. Unfortunately it produced the same result.

Comment: I am getting "foo" for name and "FooExtended" for class

Comment: I get that when I say GetMap(map, "foo") but when I say GetMap(map, "Foo") it doesn't acknowledge that "Foo" has a parent of "foo". Maybe my naming could've been better.

Comment: Oh, you want to go backwards up the chain too? I guess I was confused. Hold on.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Thanks

Comment: @nfplee Done. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Carson. I've done the refactoring and I hope you don't mind but I've updated your answer with the improvements.

Comment: @nfplee Not in the least, good work! Glad I could help you some.